# Way to calculate the variance or SE of correlation from Fisher's z

Tags: data-transformation, meta-analysis, effect-size

Is there any way to get the sampling variance of correlation given Fisher's z and its variance? To make it more clear: suppose `z = 0.5493` and `var(z) = 0.0103`. Transforming `z` to `r` will give us `r = 0.55`. Now, what I need is `var(r)`.

Thank you!

Comment: r only has a solvable standard error when it equals zero. This is a primary purpose of Fisher's Zr transformation -- it results in a value with an easy-to-compute standard error. Why do you need the SE for r? Do whatever you need on Zr (such as creating confidence intervals) and then transform back to r.

Comment: For non-zero values of r, the sampling distribution is non-symmetrical. For example, if r = .9, the right-side of the sampling distribution is constrained to the range of .9 to 1.0. However, on the left side it has the possible range of -1.0 to 0.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option than using the delta method is to make use of the fact that the sampling variance of Fisher's $Z$ values is $1/(N-3)$ where $N$ is the sample size.

The variance of $Z$ ($Var(Z)$) is reported, so the $N$ can be computed with
$$
N = \frac{1}{Var(Z)}+3.
$$

$N$ can then be used to compute the sampling variance of the correlation using the well-known formula for this (see for example equation (6.1) in the meta-analysis book by Borenstein et al. (2009)),

$$
Var(r) = \frac{(1-r^2)^2}{n-1}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful!

Comment: I believe that this is only an approximation but one that is usually sufficient for meta-analysis. It performs best for smaller values of r.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is done with the delta method.  Let $g(Z)$ be some transformation of a random variable.  Then  $\operatorname{Var}(g(Z)) = \operatorname{Var}(Z)[g'(Z)]^2$.

In this case, $g(Z) = \tanh(Z)$, so some calculus can help us get to where we need to go.

$$\operatorname{Var}(g(Z)) = 0.0103 \times [1 - \tanh^2(0.5493)]^2 \approx  0.005793821$$

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Very useful insight!